# show failed test results instead of generic message

Tags: postman

I am running a test and if it fails the result is

> Status code is 200 | AssertionError: expected response to have status
> code 200 but got 404

It would be useful to see the result failed message.  I am printing it to the console, but not sure how to get it show up on the test results as well.

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

const response = pm.response.json();

console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add it to the test name, like this:

```js
const response = pm.response.json();

pm.test(`Test something - ${response}`, () => {...})
```

Depending on the data returned, this would look awful for larger responses.

Not sure what this is giving you though...the console is the best place to print that type of debugging information.

Comment: This will make the test fail the first 200, then pass the 'test something' method.  I want the test to fail NOT pass.  I am trying to do a report and show the test passed and failed results.  But on the failed, I am asked to show the failed results as well.

Comment: I posted an example of how the response _could_ be written in the test results section, it wasn't a solution. I didn't say use that test in your collection.